# Cofinality of $2^{\aleph_\omega}$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals

Is the following statement correct: $\operatorname{cf} (2^{\aleph_\omega})=\aleph_0$? It appears in the book "Introduction To Set Theory" by Thomas Jech (page 165).

Comment: Can you show us how you derived $\operatorname{cf}(2^{\aleph_\omega}) = \aleph_0$?

Comment: Even without looking at the truth values of the two statements, they don't give any direct contradiction. Plenty of linear orders have the same cofinality. $\aleph_0$ and $\aleph_\omega$ both have cofinality $\aleph_0$.

Comment: No, by Königs Theorem $cf(\lambda^{\kappa}) > \kappa$

Comment: @bof I have modified question according to your comment.

Comment: I don't have a copy of that book, but if Jech really wrote $\operatorname{cf} (2^{\aleph_\omega})=\aleph_0$ (which is incorrect) it's obviously a typo and should read $\operatorname{cf} (\aleph_\omega)=\aleph_0$

Answer (score 5):

Assuming the Axiom of Choice, $\operatorname{cf}(2^{\aleph_\omega})\gt\aleph_0$. This is a consequence of [König's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K%C3%B6nig%27s_theorem_(set_theory)), which says that, if $m_i\lt n_i$ holds for each $i\in I$, then $$\sum_{i\in I}m_i\lt\prod_{i\in I}n_i.$$
Hence, if $m_i\lt2^{\aleph_\omega}$ for each $i\lt\omega$, then
$$\sum_{i\lt\omega}m_i\lt(2^{\aleph_\omega})^{\aleph_0}=2^{\aleph_\omega\cdot\aleph_0}=2^{\aleph_\omega}.$$
A similar argument shows that $\operatorname{cf}(2^{\aleph_\omega})\gt\aleph_\omega.$

I don't have a copy of Jech's *Introduction to Set Theory*, but if it really says $\operatorname{cf}(2^{\aleph_\omega})=\aleph_0$ that's obviously a typo for $\operatorname{cf}(\aleph_\omega)=\aleph_0$. We know that $2^{\aleph_0}\ne\aleph_\omega$ because $\operatorname{cf}(2^{\aleph_0})\gt\aleph_0=\operatorname{cf}(\aleph_\omega)$.

Comment: According to Google Books, this is indeed what it says. I agree it's an obvious typo.